# socket_connect(): unable to connect [111]: Connection refused - Printing with PHP

Tags: php, sockets, printing

We are using PHP to print labels to a Datamax printer.

Occasionally these fail to print and any subsequent attempts to connect give the error:

```
socket_connect(): unable to connect [111]: Connection refused - Printing with PHP
```

Rebooting the printer resolves the problem.

Any ideas how I can troubleshoot this?

Mick